# Stripes JsonResolution causing stackoverflowerror on Hibernate many to one mapping

Tags: java, json, stripes

I've been online trying to fix this for awhile now.

I have an object, which has successfully mapped (including JsonResolution) by using 
But when I use the many-to-one mapping for a different relationship the JsonResolution causes a stackoverflow error, I think its getting stuck in a loop on that relationship. I've tried lazy loading, Hibernate.Initialize e.t.c and no luck, I think something needs to be corrected either on the JsonResolution end or with the mapping.

```
<set name="Audits" table="audits" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="entityId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Audit" />
        </set>

<many-to-one name="person" class="Person" column="personId" not-null="false" unique="true" />
```

code:

```
@HandlesEvent("getall")
    public Resolution getall() {
        if(!User.isLoggedInUserAdmin()) { return null; }
        EventDTO eDTO = new EventDTO();
        Session s = DBUtil.GetHibernateSession();
        List<Event> events = s.createCriteria(Event.class)
                .setMaxResults(2)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("type", "Accident"))
                .addOrder(Order.desc("id"))
                .list();
        if(events.isEmpty()) { 
            eDTO.setStatus("success");
        } else {
            for(int i=0; i< events.size(); i++) {
                Hibernate.initialize(events.get(i).getPerson());
            }
            eDTO.setEntities(events);
            eDTO.setStatus("success");
        }
        JsonResolution j = (JsonResolution) new JsonResolution(eDTO);
        s.close();
        return j;
    }
```

error:

```
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesServletException: ActionBean execution threw an exception.
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:183)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:247)
root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:937)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:171)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1524)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably serialization cannot cope with circular reference (Event -> Person & Person-> Event).
Try to use your own serialization implementation (I don't know whether you can plug your own serializer or not) or use another library ([Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) maybe?) for serialization.